# Setting up PostgreSQL for forked rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have forked the development version of a Rails app I've started contributing to onto my laptop, and it uses PostgreSQL as it's database.

I have already installed postgresql with brew, what should I do next?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the gems using `bundle install`
2. Add your db credentials to config/database.yml under the 'development' section

It will look something like

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <db_name>
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: <postgres username>
  password: <postgres_password>
```

1. Run `rake db:create`
2. Run `rake db:migrate`
3. Start the server using `rails server`

And you are good to go.